# Deploy a request data flutter app on a hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, post, web-applications, hosting

Maybe for the title it is not clear what i want.

I develop an angularJS web app and deploy in firebase hosting to request data to a server (post method) and then store the data received in the firestore. I want to do request repeatedly. I dont know if it is possible with this aproach because i only can do this when the web app is active.

What i want is an app (webapp, flutter app, process or something) that could be deployed (executed) in a hosting (firebase preferably) to do this requests repeteadly. I dont know which the better solution.